# Function with same derivative

Tags: derivatives

If the function $y= e^x$ is such that its derivative is itself $dy/dx = e^x$,
does that mean the second derivative $d^2y/dx^2= e^x$?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does! And the third and the fourth and fifth derivatives and so on. It's just taking the derivative of the previous derivative and since that's the same, so is every subsequent derivative.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, you can see this by noting the second derivative is just the first derivative of the first derivative, that is:

$${d^2y\over dx^2} = {d\over dx}\left({dy\over dx}\right) = {d\over dx}(e^x) = e^x.$$

Answer (score 0):

Not only is the second derivative, but all of them are! We can actually prove it as follows:

We use as a starting point that the derivative of $f(x) = e^x$,

$${df \over dx} = f$$

that is,

$${d \over dx}(e^x) = e^x$$

Now let $k$ be the smallest natural number such that

$${d^k\over dx^k}(e^x) \neq e^x$$

Now let us consider the derivative

$${d^{k-1}\over dx^{k-1}}(e^x)$$

Because $k$ is the smallest natural number for which the derivative of $e^x$ is **not** $e^x$, the $(k-1)$*th* derivative of $e^x$ is still $e^x$:

$${d^{k-1}\over dx^{k-1}}(e^x) = e^x;\\
{d^k\over dx^k}(e^x) = {d \over dx}\left({d^{k-1}\over dx^{k-1}}(e^x)\right) = {d\over dx}(e^x) = e^x$$

and therefore the $k$*th* derivative of $e^x$ cannot be different from $e^x$, if we know that ${d\over dx}(e^x) = e^x$.